# ReferenceError, meteor

Tags: meteor, referenceerror

I've seen this problem posted but did not really understand the explanations. I am new to meteor and doing this project. From what I understand some of the functionality with node is not available in the browser, but I am unsure of how to fix the problem. I have tried to wrap the code within some function(window) but still was not able to get it working. I also tried to use npm but was coming up empty with some errors about some Illegal tokens. Thanks for any help.

Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

```
/home/alex/TacticsTrainer2/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:186
}).run();
   ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at app/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:353
    at app/js/bootstrap.min.js:8:3
    at /home/alex/TacticsTrainer2/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/alex/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules    /underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /home/alex/TacticsTrainer2/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have not structured your app correctly. You have code that is intended to run on the client/browser side that is running on the server side.

In your app:

- place all code to be run on the client in the /client directory
- place all server side code in the /server directory
- place code that you want to run on both the server and client in the root folder or a non reserved name (public, private, tests, server or client)

For more details about this see the meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: Hi, Yes that may be the problem. I ran meteor, saw the errors, then tried to mv some of the files from the server to the client directory, but it does not seem to update it; when I close and open it again the file I just moved appears in its former location. Could you explain what the best way to place code in the client directory is? Thanks for the response.

Comment: @user3723488 I'm quite confused at your applications structure, If the files move from place to place this git may be helpful to keep files in good shape. I hope you are not updating the files in the hidden .meteor directory and are instead changing the files actually in your application

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I was able to get it running. I wasn't accustomed to the meteor structure and mistakenly left code out of the  files that are created when you make the initial meteor project.

Comment: This answer doesn't address ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

[ReferenceError](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_referenceerror) is a Node error.  Meteor is a framework on top of Node.

Node has a global scope (aka Node's `global` variable).  **This error is thrown by Node (not Meteor) if you try to access an undefined global variable.**

Browsers also have a global scope called `window`, and do not throw ReferenceErrors when undefined variables are accessed.

Here's a pattern I like for adding functionality to a class (it's very Meteor):

```
/lib/Helpers.js      <-- Helpers for everyone (node+browser)
/server/Helpers.js   <-- Server helpers (node)
/client/Helpers.js   <-- Client helpers (browser)
```

Consider these implementations:

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
Helpers = {/* functions */};  // Assigned to window.Helpers and global.Helpers

// /server/Helpers.js
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/*more functions*/}

// /client/Helpers.js
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/*more functions*/}
```

This is a trivial example.  What if I didn't want to worry about load order?  Why not _.extend() in /lib/Helpers.js?

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
// Helpers = {/* functions */};                  // Overwrites...
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/* functions */});  // ReferenceError
```

Because you'll get a ReferenceError from Node if Helpers isn't defined - specifically the "Helpers" used as an argument.  (Node knows to assign Helpers as global.Helpers).

**Here are two ways to "fix" this:**

1) Assign Helpers to something

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
if (typeof Helpers === 'undefined') Helpers = {};
Helpers = _.extend(Helpers, {/* functions */});
```

2) Use helpers from the global

```
// /lib/Helpers.js
Helpers = _.extend(global.Helpers, {/* functions */});  // works in node, but...
```

**Both of which suck.**

1)'s syntax is horrible.
  2) works in node, but there is no global in browsers.  So it fails it's purpose.

So I gave up and went back to overwriting it the first time in lib, and looking for runtime errors if anything was overwritten.

If you have a handy cross-browser syntax for this, do comment :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are calling a method that is loaded on the client and server.

You could write the code inside the Meteor.method like this:

```
if (!this.isSimulation) {
    // code with node js that should only run in the server
} else {
    // code that doesn't have nodejs runtime (browser)
}
```

This happens when you loaded the Method both in the client and server.